# How long does it take for a US citizen to get a visa to travel to Israel?

Tags: visas, usa, israel, us-citizens

I just want to know how far in advance I need to plan these kind of logistics.

Comment: What country are you from?

Comment: It looks like a US citizen doesn't need to get a visa if staying less than 90 days.

Answer (score 9):

Here we go:

[List of visa requirements for travel to Israel](http://www.mfa.gov.il/NR/rdonlyres/05664082-4C0C-4C2E-A593-C9D0C0B20C2A/0/VisaRequirements.pdf)

United States citizen is exempt and no fee is charged. The document is from the Israel Ministry of Foreign Affairs.

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm not seeing how long the processing might take. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @lesley: What processing?  Are you planning on staying more than 90 days?  If not, then there's nothing to process!

Comment: The only process is a relatively quick passport check.

Comment: There is nothing to process they just stamp your passport at the Airport and you are good to go. For something other than a tourist visa call your nearest Israeli consulate and ask.